# Dart googleapis 0.35.0 - Google Drive API v3 - fields request parameter

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, dart

Google Drive API v3 [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration):

> Full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the fields query parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.

Either there is a `fields` request (query) parameter in the googleapis Dart library (which I can't find) or the library is useless for Google Drive API v3. Or maybe a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means that some HTTP requests (in the underlying web api) require a additional `?fields='...'` parameter to know what fields to include in the response. That documentation page helpfully gives a list of fields but does not say which requests require the parameter.

I personally find neither the Google api pages nor the [Dart Google API libraries](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/googleapis/0.35.0/index.html) documentation to be very helpful, however, the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) allows all the apis to be executed and tested. I used this tool to figure out what inputs are required for each web request and to make sure my Dart code was getting expected results.

Edit:

Every request in the api MAY include a `?fields='...'` parameter, but don't have to.

> If left unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are
>   returned.

So depending on what you are doing you may not need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In Drive API v2 the response contained all the properties of a resource. For performance reasons you could limit the size of a response with the `fields` parmeter. In Drive API v3 it's the other way around, the default response only contains a (very small) subset of properties. Therefor you _must use_ the `fields` parameter to get what you want. My problem is that I can't find out how to use the `fields` parameter in the googleapis library.

Comment: There is this page, explaining which fileds are possible for the different resources:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#fields
Generally I find the concept useful, since it reduces traffic, but the respective documentation is incomplete... actually there is a lot of information, but is pretty badly scattered. Most useful for understanding fields is this: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the fields need to be added to the URL

https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/blob/571f592976b7cf557d94bd0fc61b412fc1087446/generated/googleapis/lib/drive/v3.dart#L87

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance#partial

> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/demo/v1?key=YOUR-API-KEY&fields=kind,items(title,characteristics/length)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you saying that the googleapis library need to change? Or that I somehow can accomplish this on my own?